# How to install all packages listed on "apt-get list" command?

Tags: package-management

I am using Ubuntu Disco Dingo 19.04. I want to learn how to install all packages automatically that are listed by typing "apt-get list" on terminal. Not all of them are installed by default. 
I mean printing all of them to a install.sh file in first, and them install them.
Thanks!

Comment: You don't want *all* available packages, unfiltered. That would be terabytes of software which you can't ever use. Plus, there will be conflicts between quite a few of them. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: FYI `apt list | wc -l` returns 58614 lines in 16.04.6 LTS.